How can i fix error with acception to file JSON/Java
java.io.FileNotFoundException Create breakpoint: src/main/resources/autori.jon (H такого файла или каталога)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:213)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:152)
at com.fasterml.jackson.core.TokenStreamFactory._fileInputStream(TokenStreamFactory.java: 318)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory-java:1208)
at com.fasterml.jackson.databind.0bjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java: 3731)
at org.example.Biblioteca.Autor.autorDinJson(Autor.java: 81)
at org. example.Main.main (Main.java: 34)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException Create breakpoint: Cannot invoke "java.util. List. forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)" because
"autori" is null
at org. example.Main.main(Main.java:35)


Ошибка java.io.FileNotFoundException указывает на то, что приложение не может найти или открыть файл autori.json в директории src/main/resources. Это может быть вызвано несколькими причинами:
Неправильный путь к файлу: Убедитесь, что файл autori.json действительно находится в директории src/main/resources. Также проверьте, нет ли опечатки в имени файла в коде.
Файл не включен в сборку: Если вы используете систему сборки, например, Maven или Gradle, убедитесь, что директория resources корректно настроена, и файлы из неё копируются в итоговую сборку.
Запуск из неправильной директории: Если вы запускаете приложение из командной строки или из IDE, убедитесь, что текущая рабочая директория соответствует ожидаемой. В IDE, такой как IntelliJ IDEA или Eclipse, путь к ресурсам может настраиваться в настройках проекта.
проблема разрешена
